# What is the meaning of [P1-start*] in the JSF specification

Tags: java, jsf, specifications

I'm reading the JSF specification. And I came along tags like

```
[P1-start-currentPhaseId]...[P1-end]
```

I noticed that there are different tags, starting with `P1`, `P2` and `P3`. Following these is either a `-` dash or a  space.

I assume they are meant to indicate formal/normative specification, and separate it from informal/non-normative parts of the specification. But then again, there are paragraphs which are explicitly marked as non-normative.

I'm curious to the exact meaning of these tags. The differences in `P1`, `P2` and `P3` or whether these are followed by either a `-` dash or a  space. Were are these tags specified? Are they used  in other JSR's also or is this a JSF specific notation?

Comment: I can't find an explanation.  If you really want to know, I suggest you contact the document's editor.